# Why is it $q^2$ for the individual count in hardy weinberg?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, hardy-weinberg

My understanding:

In Hardy-Weinberg problems the frequency of a homozygous recessive genetic occurrence in a population is $q^2$. So if 1 in 100 people in a population have albinism (homozygous recessive disorder) then we say the frequency is $q^2=1/100$.

We then say, to find the frequency of the allele count $q$ that $q=\sqrt{1/100}= 1/10$.

I don't understand why we say this. Why would the allele count be the square root of the population frequency? There's 2 alleles per person. Why isn't it x2 or /2 instead?
I suppose my problem is understand **what exactly is p and q**.

Comment: **p** and **q** are allele frequencies. Did you search anything about Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium.

Comment: Yes but I'm having problems seeing why why square them.

Comment: Squaring is for genotypes.

Comment: This seems a very nice site: http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/hardy-weinberg-equation-299. I'm not answering this because it's too long ago I took this class, but Nature has awesome basic explanations of a lot of stuff. And it's credible. Check it out!

Comment: WYSIWYG you're not understanding the depth of my question.

I think this may actually be too mathematically difficult to answer on biology stackexchange upon further examination.

Comment: @paze If you think so,you are dramatically overestimating the difficulty of this question.

Comment: Could you answer it then please?

Comment: Okay . If **p** is probability of allele-**A** then what is the probability of **A** mating with another **A**; **p×p=p²**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, let me correct your equation: $q = \sqrt{\frac{1}{100}} = \frac{1}{10} = 0.1 ≠ 10 $.

**From allele frequency to genotype frequency**

Imagine you were to randomly sample an allele from a population of allele where the allele `A` is present at frequency $q$. What is the probability that you draw allele `A`? Answer: $P(A) = q$. Now, put this allele back in the pool and imagine you have to draw two alleles. What is the probability that the two alleles are `A`. Well it is the probability that the first allele is `A` times the probability that the second allele is `A`, it is $P(A) \cdot P(A) = q \cdot q = q^2$.

**From genotype frequency to allele frequency**

Therefore, under Hardy-Weinberg conditions, if the allele `A` is at frequency $q$, then the homozygote genotype `AA` is at frequency $q \cdot q = q^2$. Now let's denote the frequency of the genotype `AA` by $f_{AA}$. You know that $f_{AA} = q^2$ from the above though experiment. If you take the square root of both sides, you get $\sqrt{f_{AA}} = \sqrt{q^2} = q$. In words, the frequency of the allele `A` is the square root of the frequency of the genotype `AA`.

**Recessivity and dominance**

Btw, you'll note that those calculations tell nothing about the patterns of dominance/recessivity of alleles (Hardy-Weinberg principle assumes no selection anyway).

Comment: also 1/100 != 1/10

Comment: Ha ha oops. I forgot the square root. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To understand population genetics and the Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium you first need to clearly separate **genotype frequencies** (the frequency of individuals in a population having a genotype) and **allele frequencies** (the frequency of an allele in the population gene pool). In your question **p** and **q** represents allele frequencies, while **p<sup>2</sup>**, **q<sup>2</sup>** and **2pq** represents genotype frequencies (if $p=P(A)$, $p^2$ is $P(AA)$). Genotype frequencies can be thought of as the probability that two particular alleles are located in the same individual, and the calculation of these probabilities is a simple application of the [multiplication rule of probabilites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events) for independent events.

Therefore, if the allele frequency **p** is 0.2 the probability of having two copies of this allele is $p \times p = p^2 = 0.2^2 = 0.04$. If there are only two alleles in the population, q has to be 0.8, which means that the other two genotype frequencies are $ 2pq = 2\times0.2\times0.8 = 0.32$ and $ q^2 = 0.8^2 = 0.64$. As you can see, these genotype frequencies also sum to 1, since they represent the genotypes of all individuals in the population,

Answer (score 0):

> In Hardy-Weinberg problems the frequency of a homozygous recessive
>   genetic occurrence in a population is q2.

Sort of but not quite. If the locus has two possible alleles, $A$ and $a$, the frequency of each allele in the population is $p$ and $q$ respectively. If the population size ($N$) is 500 diploid individuals, there are 1000  loci ($2*N$, because of diploidy) which each could have either $A$ or $a$, and each of the 500 individuals could have the genotypes $AA$, $Aa$, or $aa$. If we know that the population of loci has 100 copies of $A$ then $p = 100/1000 = 0.1$, and $q$, the frequency of $a$, must then be $1-p = q = 0.9$.

The value of $q^2$ tells us how many individuals in the population, under the assumptions of [HWE](http://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/hardy-weinberg-equation-299), will be of the genotype $aa$ - **it says nothing about the recessivity (or dominance) of the allele, nor the phenotype.** In the example above, $q^2 = 0.9^2 = 0.81$ - under assumptions of HWE 81% of the population will be genotype $aa$.

In terms of math it is simple probability theory. If we have a bag of coloured marbles, 5 red and 5 blue, the frequency of red ($p$) is 0.5, and blue ($q$) is 0.5. If we draw one marble from the bag, the probability of the marble being blue, $P(blue)$, is equal to the frequency of blue, $q$, which is 0.5. If we then return the marble to the bag and make a second draw, the probability of drawing a blue marble is again $b$, 0.5. The probability of both of the drawn marbles being blue $P(blue) * P(blue) = 0.5 * 0.5$, or $q^2$. The probability of drawing one red and one blue is $2 * p * q$, and probability of two red marbles is $p^2$.